# What is the best tool/tools to record video from webcam on linux?

Tags: recording, video

My webcam is detected correctly (and i can use it in skype without any issues), but how can i record video on linux preferably with gui tool ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Cheese (GNOME) if you just need just that, or VLC for more advanced features.

Comment: I you add program links to your answer I'll vote it up ... ;)

Comment: ubuntu install link: apt-get install cheese

Answer (score 0):

You could use Qtcam for recording videos on Linux